# Scala - currying function with implicit value

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've approached a problem with scala implicits and I am posting a simplified version here.

I have a class called SomeClass that contains a implicit val a = 3;

I have a created a trait that I intend to use with SomeClass like below:

```
 trait TestSum {
    def sum(a:Int)(b:Int)(implicit c: Int): Unit = {
      a + b + c
    }

    val sum_a = sum(1) _
  }
```

Sum_a obviously will not work, because it requires an implicit value c, which is accessible in SomeClass scope. Moving sum_a to SomeClass solves the issue but messes a bit in my code. Is there any good solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could require the implicit to exist in the implementor like this:

```
trait TestSum {
  implicit def c: Int

  def sum(a:Int)(b:Int): Unit = {
    a + b + c
  }

  val sum_a = sum(1) _
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Functions in Scala cannot have implicit parameters, so when you do eta-expansion (the `_`) on a method to turn it into a function, it will look right then and there for a valid implicit parameter in scope to fill it in. As it stands, your code does not have an implicit `Int` in scope so the expansion fails. If you move it into `SomeClass` which does have an implicit `Int`, it will use that `Int` where the implicit is expected.

For instance:

```
scala> def foo(i: Int)(implicit s: String): String = i.toString ++ " " ++ s
foo: (i: Int)(implicit s: String)String

scala> foo _
<console>:10: error: could not find implicit value for parameter s: String
              foo _
              ^

scala> implicit val s: String = "number"
s: String = number

scala> foo _
res1: Int => String = <function1>

scala> res1(5)
res2: String = 5 number
```

More info can be found here: http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/09/methods-functions.html

Comment: Yes, I know why it does not work, I am just curious if there is any way to walk around this problem and keep the code more or less clean.